# Запустить скрипт и завершить его до монтирования разделов из fstab

Tags: linux, mount

ДД, коллеги!

Есть задача по обработки запросов I/O к сушествующему блочному устройству. Другими словами, есть диск /dev/sdb и весь ввод-вывод проходит через мой фильтр-драйвер. Эта задача решена, драйвер написан и отлажен, управляющая программа (будем её называть **crcp**) тоже. 
Теперь мне необходимо сделать так, что бы мой драйвер-фильтр инициировался специальной управляюшей программой (**crcp**) и должно это происходить **до проверки разделов** (checkfs ?) на /dev/sdb на предмет наличия разделов и, **до монтирования** разделов из fstab (mountall ?).

Я пытался достичь решения задачи посредством написания LSB-скрипта и встраивания его в цепочку зависимостей-загрузки - безуспешно. Я не смог добиться того, что бы любые попытки работать с разделами на /dev/sdb гарантировались до монтирования разделов.

Эту проблему я описал вот [тут](https://superuser.com/questions/1289190/execute-script-at-system-startup-time-before-mounting-disks-from-fstab).

Прошу помощи. Мне хотелось бы использовать максимально универсальный путь.

Comment: если дело на современных бубунтах, то может стоит написать systemd Unit? я не уверен, что со всеми наворотами systemd обычный sysv скрипт можно безболезненно вклинить так рано в загрузку... И по общему дизайну, может вместо того, чтобы фильтровать доступ к существующему устройству драйвер будет экспортировать фильтрованную версию в отдельное устройство, как это происходит в dm-подсистеме?

Comment: Ваш вариант рассматривался, но ... задание я получил на тот , что описан. :-) Если вы под systemd Unit имели ввиду нечто похожее на /etc/init.d/skeleton - то ... таки да, этот путь был испробован.

Comment: В сей момент я пробую под ubuntu 16+, но предполагается использование и в Debian, и прочих наборах Linuks.

Comment: Нет, systemd юниты — это то что в `/etc/system.d/system/`. То что в `/etc/init.d` — это sysv сценарии. На ubuntu-14+ и debian-8+ systemd — система инициализации по умолчанию, заменившая upstart или sysv-init... совместимость с sysv скриптами поддерживается, но я сомневаюсь, что настолько глубоко, чтобы ничего не сломать в ранней инициализации...  Честно сказать, я не очень уверенно знаю детали устройства systemd, так что не могу сказать что именно делать, но копать я бы попробовал в эту сторону...

Comment: @Fat-Zer,  добро, принял, изучу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Был выбран путь внедрения кода в initrd/initramfs, и использование триггеров: local-premount.